# SVGR custom template variables undefined when used in import

Tags: node.js, babeljs, svgr

In addition to creating a React component using an [SVGR custom template](https://react-svgr.com/docs/custom-templates/), I'm trying to create a Storybook story to be generated alongside the component. The problem comes when I try to use the provided `variable.componentName` as a location for an import declaration in the template. Using `componentName` anywhere else in the template works as intended, it's only an issue when used with an import declaration. The template code is as follows:

```js
const template = (variables, { tpl }) => {
  return tpl`
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import View from './${variables.componentName}';

type Story = StoryObj<typeof View>;

const meta: Meta<typeof View> = {
  component: View,
};

export default meta;

export const ${variables.componentName}: Story = {};
`;
};

module.exports = template
```

I receive the following CLI errors:

`Failed to handle file:  src/svgs/example-icon.svg`

followed by

`Error: /Users/.../icons/src/svgs/example-icon.svg: Unknown substitution "$$BABEL_TPL$1" given ...`

What can I do to fix this?

For what it's worth, the following is the script I'm running:

```
"generate": "svgr --out-dir ./src/components --template ./src/templates/Component.js ./src/svgs --typescript --jsx-runtime 'automatic' && svgr --out-dir ./src/components --template ./src/templates/Story.js ./src/svgs --ext stories.tsx --typescript",
```